# I have broken screen. Can I root my phone only with downloading mode and recovering mode?

Tags: rooting, adb, samsung-galaxy-s-duos, broken-screen

I want to recover my data from my Samsung S Duos. I have broken screen, so I can't do anything, even unlock (because I have a password to enter the phone). I tried to install CWM and connect with ADB, but USB debugging isn't turn on, so I can't connect with ADB at all. Is there some way to root my phone via recovering mode (with CWM) so I can turn on USB debugging and work with ADB? Maybe there is some easier way to recover my data? I thought e.g. about connecting keyboard to my phone, so I can unlock it and normally connect via USB, but my phone doesn't support OTG :/ any ideas?

Comment: Can you access CWM via adb? Also, which version of Android is your phone running?

Comment: I don't know, how to access CWM via adb? My phone is detected by computer, but the content is blocked, because of the password so is there a way to use adb then? Android 4.0

Comment: Just buy a new screen digitizer, you're lucky, they go about $15 for your particular model. Use Youtube to guide you through the process. And use a hair blow dryer to heat the glue off the screen. The new screen digitizer usually comes with a plastic separator tool thingy to help you separate the old screen.

Comment: Second option: if the screen is only partially broken, you can root your device, and replace the password pattern file. This way, any pattern, or any password, will be able to open your device, if the device can't find that file. But I agree with the answer's advice, you should definitely try to backup your device through recovery mode (which you should be able to do).

Comment: I made backup and got the needed data. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to use `adb` on your phone while in recovery. `adb devices` should show something along the lines of `YOUR_DEVICE   recovery`.

Once you have access to your device in recovery, you can mount the data partition using `adb shell busybox mount /data` and then you can use `adb pull` to pull data from the data partition, for example: `adb pull /data/ phone_data/` will save the entire contents of your /data partition (which includes apps, wifi settings and app preferences) to phone_data in your current directory. If you want to pull data from your sd card for some reason, simply do `adb pull /sdcard/ phone_sdcard/`.

*Note*: I prefer using TWRP (which you can find for your device [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2726125)), so if any of the above steps don't work you should try using it.

Comment: That requires custom recovery. On Alcatel Pop C9, I can't even go to Download/Fastboot mode to install a custom recovery (though the phone _is_ rooted). Any ideas?

Comment: How do you do this when using FDE (full-disk-encryption)?